# Extract files from a corrupted .gz file

Tags: tar, data-recovery, gzip

I tried to compress a directory using `tar -zcvf output.gz input_dir`. I suppose I should have used a `.tgz` extension for compressing.

How do I untar `output.gz`? I tried both `tar zxvf output.gz`, which didn't yield anything, and `gunzip output.gz`, which resulted in a corrupted archive.

Is there a proper way of extracting `output.gz`?

Comment: There must be some other reason why the archive is corrupted, just having the wrong file name is not enough for that. What happens if you `cp output.gz output.tar.gz`, and then run `gunzip output.tar.gz`, and after that run `tar tvfz output.tar`?

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, It ended up with the following error,            **gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors**

Comment: So, the compressed archive is corrupted somehow, or it is not compressed at all. Have you looked inside the file with `less`? Could you copy-paste a couple of lines from the file to your question?

Comment: There are two cases: less output.gz yields **hope_blaze_ddr/^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@**                                less output.tar.gz yields  :                                                                    **drwxr-xr-x   eng      0 2015-05-07 11:11:54 hope_blaze_ddr/
-rw-r--r--  eng  12292 2015-04-14 14:09:30 hope_blaze_ddr/.DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  eng      0 2015-04-28 08:49:12 hope_blaze_ddr/gtxe2_top_v1_00_a/**    . The second case just points to the file paths contained in the original directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 tar -zcvf output.gz input_dir
```

Wrong!

```
 tar -zcvf output.tar.gz input_dir
```

or

```
 tar -zcvf output.tgz input_dir
```

Good.

Then estract with

```
tar -xvf output.tgz
```

or

```
tar -xvf output.tar.gz
```

You can omit z on modern distro,if doesn't work or using old distro use z switch

Comment: Basically the concept is right, one should use the correct extensions. However, it doesn't matter if one doesn't use the right extension, since the software doesn't care about the filename.

Comment: @elbarna : I agree with your suggestion, but I have already compressed the file the **Wrong** way and I don't have the original uncompressed directory , hence was looking for any feasible solutions

Comment: `file yourfile.tgz` what report?

Comment: @elbarna , output.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Thu May  7 12:08:00 2015

Comment: try this,`gzip -d output.gz` and file output,if file output return tar archive,tar -xvf output,if return error i think is corrupted and lost forever,but before delete try for recovering on google

Comment: @elbarna , wow that worked !! Thanks a lot.